# How to change corner radius when reaching the bottom of the window

Tags: flutter

I'm having the following widget that can shrink / expand dynamically depending on the content.

[image]

When there is a lot of content, the widget expands vertically to reach the bottom of the window. When it reaches the bottom of the window, I would like to change the corner radius of the container from the current value to 0, effectively making it look like a bottom sheet panel.

[image]

The code for the above screenshot is:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO
    // THIS VALUE SHOULD CHANGE SOMEHOW
    const radiusBottom = Radius.circular(16);
    const radiusTop = Radius.circular(16);

    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: radiusTop,
                topRight: radiusTop,
                bottomLeft: radiusBottom,
                bottomRight: radiusBottom,
              ),
            ),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    Container(
                      width: 200,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      child: Text(
                        "item $i",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have got your problem, I have achieved this:

[image]

when it reaches the end

[image]

You can further improve. Here's how I did this:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double radiusBottom = 16.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const radiusTop = Radius.circular(16);

    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: radiusTop,
                topRight: radiusTop,
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(radiusBottom),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(radiusBottom),
              ),
            ),
            child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
              onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
                if (scrollNotification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
                  final maxScroll = scrollNotification.metrics.maxScrollExtent;
                  final currentScroll = scrollNotification.metrics.pixels;

                  if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= 0) {
                    setState(() {
                      radiusBottom = 0.0;
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      radiusBottom = 16.0;
                    });
                  }
                }
                return false;
              },
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                      Container(
                        width: 200,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: Text(
                          "item $i",
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it doesn't solve the problem. You are changing the corner radius based on the scroll position, and not based on whether the content has exceeded the available height or not.

Comment: Updated, so now when content is at the end, it will change the border

Comment: Again. This is not about scrolling area. Is about the widget height and how it correlates to the parent, in this case the entire window. The bottom corners should be circular ONLY if the widget bottom is the same than the window bottom.